# Best practice signing debian packages

Tags: debian, packaging, deb

On my environment the packages are created by running 'debuild -b' and uploaded to the debian repository with dput. The debuild step is telling me that the package has been signed so should be cool. I have my keys generated with gpg, it's asking for the passphrase, no problem here I guess.

The debian repository has mini-dinstall running as daemon.

Now when I'm installing the new package from the repository server and I got the 'signature could not be verified' warning. Where is the missing/wrong step(s) and what are the best practices to sign the deb packages?

Comment: Does the system installing the package trust the GPG key that was used to build the repository?

Comment: Yes, I used apt-key add and after I signed the release everything works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to Debian packages and archives there are two types of signing. The first is the actual `.deb` files (and `.orig.tar.gz`, `.changes` and `.dsc`), and the second is the generated archive metadata (the `Release` file specifically). The signing that happens as part of `debuild` is the former, and this signature is only used to verify that you're allowed to add packages to the archive (i.e. it is checked by `reprepro` or `mini-dinstall` as part of the incoming package processing). The latter type of signing needs to be done by the archive manager (`reprepro`, `mini-dinstall`, or sometimes manually), and this is the signature which is verified by `aptitude` and `apt-get` when downloading and installing packages.

It sounds like you haven't setup signing of the generated archive metadata. You can either do this by creating and configuring `mini-dinstall` with a [release_signscript](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/mini-dinstall.1.html#contenttoc4), or by manually signing the `Release` file and putting the signature in `Release.gpg` everytime the archive is changed. You then obviously need to add the key on the machines installing the packages using `apt-key`.